# Javascript refactoring boilerplate into decorators for chat app event handler

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, decorator, es6-class, ecmascript-2016

I'm writing an event handler class for a messaging app, and I have some code that looks like so:

```
class EventHandler {
  constructor(client, chatroomManager) {
    this.client = client;
    this.chatroomManager = chatroomManager;
  }

  handleJoin(roomId, cb) {
    ...
  }

  handleLeave(roomId, cb) {
    if (!this.client.isLoggedIn()) {
      cb("err");
      return;
    }
    const chatroom = this.chatroomManager.getRoomById(roomId);
    // check that chatroom exists
    if (chatroom != null) {
      // check that user was already in the room
      if (chatroom.getRoomId() in this.client.rooms) {
        chatroom.removeUser(this.client);
      } else {
        cb("error")
      }
    } else {
      cb("error");
    }
  }

  handleMessage(roomId, message, cb) {
    if (!this.client.isLoggedIn()) {
      cb("err");
      return;
    }
    const chatroom = this.chatroomManager.getRoomById(roomId);
    // check that chatroom exists
    if (chatroom != null) {
      // check that user was already in the room
      if (chatroom.getRoomId() in this.client.rooms) {
        chatroom.addEntry(this.client.username, message);
      } else {
        cb("error")
      }
    } else {
      cb("error");
    }
  }

}
```

As you can see, there is a lot of repeated code in the `handleLeave` and `handleMessage` methods (and even more methods in the full code). I want to get rid of this as much as possible.

First of all, I expect that I might be able to replace the first `if` statement with an ES7 decorator, like so:

```
class EventHandler {
  ...

  @requirelogin
  handleLeave(roomId, cb) {
    const chatroom = this.chatroomManager.getRoomById(roomId);
    // check that chatroom exists
    if (chatroom != null) {
      // check that user was already in the room
      if (chatroom.getRoomId() in this.client.rooms) {
        chatroom.removeUser(this.client);
      } else {
        cb("error")
      }
    } else {
      cb("error");
    }
  }
}
```

Secondly, I think that if I can refactor the `chatroomManager.getRoomById` method to return a Promise, then I can define a helper function:

```
validateRoom(roomId) {
  return chatroomManager.getRoomById(roomId).then(room => {
    if (roomId in this.client.rooms) {
      return room;
    } else {
      throw new Error("Client is not in room");
    }
  }
}
```

Then I can refactor like so:

```
class EventHandler {
  ...

  @requirelogin
  handleLeave(roomId, cb) {
    this.validateRoom(roomId)
        .then(room => room.removeUser(this.client))
        .catch(cb);
  }
}
```

I'm content with this, but I wonder if it can be simplified even further? It seems like this pattern of

```
this.validateRoom(roomId)
    .then(room => { /* do something */ })
    .catch(cb);
```

will still be repeated many times, and I wonder if there is a clean way to extract this (perhaps as another decorator, although I can't see how)? Ideally I would like to have a setup where the public API of `EventHandler` stays the same

```
handleLeave(roomId, cb)
handleMessage(roomId, message, cb)
```

but under the hood I am implementing something like

```
handleLeave(room) {
  room.removeUser(this.client);
}

handleMessage(room, message) {
  room.addEntry(this.client.username, message);
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this? Would I need to do any large refactoring to the code in order to do so?

Comment: "*I'm writing an event handler class for a messaging app*" - don't. You hardly need to instantiate multiple of these event handlers, do you? This seems to be the wrong abstraction. There should be a `Room` class, and one controller method that calls the respective method of the selected room. Not many methods that all take a `roomId`.

Comment: @Bergi There is a `Room` class. I'm using socket.io, so when the client emits some event, say "message", and passes the room id and message text, I need an event handler for that event. Perhaps these event handlers don't need to belong to a class, but the real issue here is how do I avoid writing all this boilerplate code to check that the client is logged in, the room exists, and the client is in the room?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the socket.io api, but does it really take an object and calls separate handler methods for separate events on that, or does it take a single event handler method and pass the event name?

Comment: Each client is represented as a `socket` object, and every time a client connects you need to setup event handlers on that `socket` object using `socket.on("event_name", handlerFunc)`. Here is a very basic example: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/examples/chat/index.js

Therefore, not only is each function defined separately, it also must operate on the `socket` object itself. Typically in the examples I've seen this is done via closures, but I decided to implement a class and pass the socket to the class instead.

Comment: Ah, yes, I'd expect something like `socket.on('leave', requireLogin(withRoom(function(room) { room.removeUser(this.client); })))`. Those two wrappers would be easier to write and understand than some fancy experimental method decorators, at least to me :-)

Comment: @Bergi For the `withRoom` wrapper, would I need to rely on `roomId` and `cb` being the first and last arguments passed to the event handler, respectively? Because the call signature for each event handler may be different depending on the event (this is user defined).

Comment: Yes, there needs to be a way to tell `withRoom` where to get the room id from. That might be dynamic with a separate helper argument, it might a signature convention, or something else.